# Is it a bad idea to do low-level image processing development via C# .NET SIMD?

Tags: c#, performance, simd

I conducted a test where I processed an image with 8 million pixels. In this test, I looped 1,036,800 times performing no operations, which took about 3-5ms. Simply executing Avx.LoadVector256(srcPtr + i * stride) took about 4-8ms. Adding a Vector256.Shuffle operation immediately increased the time to around 12ms. Further adding Avx2.UnpackLow, Avx2.UnpackHigh, Vector256.GetLower(), and GetUpper() operations, the time instantly increased to around 20ms. These operations were merely for converting a 24-bit image to an 8-bit grayscale image. Moreover, the time reached approximately 90ms when Parallel.For was not implemented.

In comparison, OpenCVSharp only took 3-6ms for the complete image type conversion. It’s frustrating to see that even a loop doing nothing takes 3-6ms, the same time OpenCVSharp takes to complete the conversion.

Are there any other ways to optimize the performance to reach 3-6ms? Or am I approaching this in a completely incorrect manner?

Image Size: 3840 x 2160
Image Type: PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

```
       const ushort mulBlue = (ushort)(0.114 * 0x10000);
       const ushort mulGreen = (ushort)(0.587 * 0x10000);
       const ushort mulRed = (ushort)(0.299 * 0x10000);

       public static void BGR24Bit2Gray(byte* src, byte* dst, int count)
       {
           var CoeB = Vector128.Create(mulBlue);
           var CoeG = Vector128.Create(mulGreen);
           var CoeR = Vector128.Create(mulRed);

           byte[] Seqdata1 = new byte[32] { 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
           byte[] Seqdata2 = new byte[32] { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

           int allPixels = count * 3;
           byte* srcEnd = src + allPixels;
           int stride = 24;
           int loopCount = (int)((srcEnd - src) / stride);

           ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions();
           pOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

           fixed (byte* pa1 = Seqdata1)
           fixed (byte* pa2 = Seqdata2)
           {
               byte* par1 = pa1;
               byte* par2 = pa2;
               byte* tdst = dst;
               Vector256<byte> seq1 = Avx.LoadVector256(par1);
               Vector128<byte> seq2 = Sse2.LoadVector128(par2);

               Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

               //for (int i = 0; i < 1036800; i++)
               //for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
               Parallel.For(0, loopCount - 1, pOptions, i =>
               {
                   var _1st24bytes = Avx.LoadVector256(src + i * stride);
                   var rslt256 = Vector256.Shuffle(_1st24bytes, seq1);
                   Vector256<ushort> v1l = Avx2.UnpackLow(rslt256, Vector256<byte>.Zero).AsUInt16();
                   Vector256<ushort> v1h = Avx2.UnpackHigh(rslt256, Vector256<byte>.Zero).AsUInt16();

                   var Bdata = v1l.GetLower();
                   var Gdata = v1h.GetLower();
                   var Rdata = v1l.GetUpper();

                   var B = Sse2.MultiplyHigh(Bdata, CoeB);
                   var G = Sse2.MultiplyHigh(Gdata, CoeG);
                   var R = Sse2.MultiplyHigh(Rdata, CoeR);

                   var Gray = Sse2.Add(B, Sse2.Add(G, R));
                   var GrayByt = Vector128.AsByte(Gray);

                   var rslt128 = Ssse3.Shuffle(GrayByt, seq2);
                   var frslt = rslt128.GetLower();

                   Sse2.Store(dst + i * 8, rslt128);
               }
               );
               sw.Stop();
               var tp = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
               tslblStatus.Text = tp.ToString() + "ms";
           }
       }

//Test Method:
private unsafe void ConvertionTest()
{
    Bitmap orgpic = pcbxOrg.Image as Bitmap;
    //Do nothing when the original image is null
    if(orgpic==null) return;
    //Only for 24 bit image processing
    if(orgpic.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) return;
    
    int width = orgpic.Width;
    int height = orgpic.Height;
    int count = width * height; //Pixel count
    
    //Define the gray image
    Bitmap despic = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    
    lock (lcobj)
    {
        //Lock the image data
        BitmapData orgData = orgpic.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, orgpic.PixelFormat);
        BitmapData desData = despic.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        //Get the image pointer
        byte* orgPtr = (byte*)orgData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* desPtr = (byte*)desData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        
        //Start convertion
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        BGR24Bit2Gray(orgPtr, desPtr, count);
        sw.Stop();
        
        //Unlock the image data
        orgpic.UnlockBits(orgData);
        despic.UnlockBits(desData);

        var tp = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        tslblStatus.Text = tp.ToString() + "ms";
    }
    //ColorPalette for the 8 bit image
    ColorPalette palette = despic.Palette;
    for (int i = 0; i != palette.Entries.Length; i++)
    {
        palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    }
    despic.Palette = palette;
    pcbxDes.Image = despic;
}
```

Could you provide some guidance on low-level image processing? I would like to know if my approach in C#.NET could be improved, or if it would be more beneficial to explore other languages. Thank you.

Comment: Doing low level optimization like this require a fairly good understanding of both the compiler and processor. In my experience, *just* switching to c++ might improve performance by a little little, if at all. But it may allow for further optimizations due to better control over the code generation. You might want to look at the generated assembly, and compare with that from OpenCV to see if there is anything odd going on. If you *really* want to push performance you might consider using the GPU instead.

Comment: also, is your code really correct? Normally the "stride" is the number of bytes of a row of pixels. And this might be larger than bytesperPixel * width due to alignment requirements. So you would typically have a outer parallel loop for rows, and an inner regular loop for pixels in a row.

Comment: @JonasH The code works fine after the test. For the "stride", it is just a name. Sorry for the confusion. I should re-name it as "stepSize".

Comment: It might work correct for your given test image, and that might be enough if you just want to get a bound on the performance. But if you intent to use the code for anything you really need to handle all the edge-cases.

Comment: @JonasH I see. In fact, Avx.LoadVector256 loads 32 bytes, but only 24 bytes (equivalent to 8 pixels) are processed. When the pointer reaches the edge, 8 bytes from the next row are also loaded, but they are not processed. Fortunately, for the last 32 bytes of data, it definitely include 8 bytes data which are not in the range of the image data, yet no error will occur when they are loaded by Avx.LoadVector256. Then I could have a completed gray image by using it.  It could be a wrong way, but that is the best I can do, now.

Comment: @JonasH You may do the same test if you are interested. I've added my test method in the code.

Comment: Another note, there can be penalties for unaligned loads with AVX. I'm note sure about the exact details, but such details can be very important for performance. One approach can be to partially unroll the loop, so the 256 and 24-bit boundaries align. But I'm not an expert on SIMD, I just know it tend to optimization tend to be really complicated when trying to extract the last bit of performance.

Comment: Using Parallel.For with a short body invoked per iteration like this would probably have add a lot of overhead, variables used inside lambdas can't be enregistered, so the loop body would be reloading them on every iteration. The way your times are scaling also makes me suspicious if they're from a debug build.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding a Vector256.Shuffle operation immediately increased the time to around 12ms.

Unfortunately `Vector256.Shuffle` is not a general-purpose shuffle generator that can solve any shuffle and implement it well in terms of SIMD instructions, there is a set of things it knows how to do and outside of that set it just gives up. I don't exactly know which cases work out well, and it's probably going to improve in newer .NET versions anyway. In any case it didn't work out well this time and the compiler (JIT compiler, not C# compiler itself) generated this:

```
L0142: vmovups [rsp+0x20], ymm2
L0148: vmovups [rsp+0x40], ymm0
L014e: xor edx, edx
L0150: lea r8, [rsp+0x40]
L0155: movsxd r10, edx
L0158: movzx r8d, byte ptr [r8+r10]
L015d: xor r9d, r9d
L0160: cmp r8d, 0x20
L0164: jge short L0173
L0166: lea r9, [rsp+0x20]
L016b: mov r8d, r8d
L016e: movzx r9d, byte ptr [r9+r8]
L0173: lea r8, [rsp+0x60]
L0178: mov [r8+r10], r9b
L017c: inc edx
L017e: cmp edx, 0x20
L0181: jl short L0150
```

Which means the vectors are both stored to memory and then an ugly scalar loop does the actual shuffling. There's no SIMD here .. except the stores before the loop.

To get actual SIMD instructions, you will have to implement the shuffle based on raw shuffling primitives such as `Avx2.Shuffle` but (and I assume this is why you didn't use it here) you will have to take care of any cross-128-bit-part data movement yourself, as `Avx2.Shuffle` aka `vpshufb` can only shuffle the bytes within each 128-bit half of a 256-bit vector, not from one half into the other.

You don't need to explicitly load vectors from memory to create a vector of constants by the way, you can write something like `Vector256.Create((byte)0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` (the weird cast to `byte` is to select the right overload).

> Further adding Avx2.UnpackLow, Avx2.UnpackHigh, Vector256.GetLower(), and GetUpper() operations, the time instantly increased to around 20ms.

There is nothing wrong with these things in isolation. `GetLower` normally doesn't even cost an instruction (whichever operation uses the result of `GetLower` can access the `xmm` part of whatever `ymm` register the value was in), the others are just normal shuffles.

`MultiplyHigh` is good but consider `MultiplyAddAdjacent` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. There’s a wealth of new knowledge for me to absorb. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's NET7 or NET8, the Shuffle method is still not hardware-accelerated and always uses scalar fallback code. I've tested this on both X86 and Arm platforms, and it's the same.

To solve the problem of the Shuffle method not being hardware accelerated, I developed the VectorTraits library. It supports both X86 and Arm platforms.

- X86 platform: Use _mm256_shuffle_epi8 and other instructions.
- Arm platforms: Use vqvtbl1q_u8 and other instructions.

The methods is as follows.

- [Vector256s.Shuffle](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.Shuffle.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_Shuffle_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Shuffle and clear. If the indices value is out of range, the element will be cleared.
- [Vector256s.YShuffleInsert](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.YShuffleInsert.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_YShuffleInsert_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Shuffle and insert. If the index value is out of range, the elements of the background vector will be inserted.
- [Vector256s.YShuffleKernel](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vector256s.YShuffleKernel.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vector256s_YShuffleKernel_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector256_System_Byte__): Only shuffle. If the index value is out of range, the result is undefined.

Not only for Vector256, but also for Vector128 and [Vector](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vectors.Shuffle.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vectors_Shuffle_System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__), this library provides a Shuffle method.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/VectorTraits

Answer (score 0):

You can get very close to low-level image processing speeds with C# (ASP.NET) using `Spans`. A very popular image processing library called **ImageSharp** allows you to do `Span` processing with these methods:

```
Image.ProcessPixelRows()
IImageProcessingContext.ProcessPixelRowsAsVector4()
```

Here is a nice article explaining how to work with pixel buffers in ImageSharp:

https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/pixelbuffers.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am trying to get more info. about it.

Comment: I did the test as below, yet it takes around 16ms...  Am I doing it correctly, please?

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.LoadPixelData<Bgr24>(rgbValues, width, height))
{
    image.Mutate(x=>x.Grayscale());
}
sw.Stop();
string msg = $"Convertion:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";